# Applescript having problems processing a dropped image file on an Application icon

Tags: macos, applescript

Hi I have this code and I can't get the code to copy the filename/dimensions into the Mac's clipboard after I drop an image file on the Applescript Application with code below. It's the dropped item code that's not right, rest works (I drop only one file on the icon).

My code is:

```
on open theDroppedItems
    
    set theCurrentItem to item a of theDroppedItems
    
    
end open

try
    
    tell application "Image Events"
        launch
        set this_image to open theCurrentItem
        copy the dimensions of this_image to {H_res, V_res}
        copy the name of this_image to originalname
        close this_image
    end tell
    
    set myvar to originalname
    set the clipboard to "src=\"" & myvar & "\"" & " width=\"" & H_res & "\"" & " width=\"" & V_res & "\""
    
end try
```

Can anyone please fix my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area between `on` and the corresponding `end` is called *scope*.

And local variables like `theCurrentItem` are only visible inside the scope they are declared in.

**Solution:** Move the code related to `Image Events` into the `on open` handler

```
on open theDroppedItems
    set theCurrentItem to item 1 of theDroppedItems
    try
        
        tell application "Image Events"
            launch
            set this_image to open theCurrentItem as «class furl»
            copy the dimensions of this_image to {H_res, V_res}
            copy the name of this_image to originalname
            close this_image
        end tell
        
        set myvar to originalname
        set the clipboard to "src=\"" & myvar & "\"" & " width=\"" & H_res & "\"" & " width=\"" & V_res & "\""
        
    end try
end open
```

**Edit:**

An alternative way is to get the dimensions from the Spotlight meta data. If the file doesn't have height and width data, an error message is copied to the clipboard.

```
on run
    open (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
end run

on open theDroppedItems
    set theCurrentItem to item 1 of theDroppedItems
    set theFile to POSIX path of theCurrentItem
    try
        set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "/"}
        set dimensions to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdls " & quoted form of theFile & space & "-name kMDItemPixelHeight -name kMDItemPixelWidth")
        set filename to last text item of theFile
        set text item delimiters to " = "
        tell dimensions
            set pixelsHeight to text item 2 of item 1
            set pixelsWidth to text item 2 of item 2
        end tell
        if pixelsHeight is "(null)" then error
        set text item delimiters to TID
        set the clipboard to "src=\"" & filename & "\"" & " height=\"" & pixelsHeight & "\"" & " width=\"" & pixelsWidth & "\""
    on error
        set text item delimiters to TID
        set the clipboard to "couldn't get dimensions of file " & filename
    end try
end open
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I tried this code but it's not working at all. The clipboard is empty after I drop a file.

Comment: Perhaps you can drop an image file and check too. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, replace `item a` with `item 1`

Comment: Sorry that mod didn't work either. Perhaps when you are on a mac, you can test your code? Thanks!

Comment: I'm so sorry it didn't work still! I saw you added the class furl code but it's not working here. The clipboard is empty after an image file is dropped on the app icon.

Comment: I tested it successfully. Debug your code. For example remove the `try` block and/or insert `display dialog` lines.

Comment: Ok i'll revert back soon.

Comment: Have you saved as "Application" or "Workflow" I"m using application. Something could be wrong with my Mac's privacy/security settings. Even display dialog doesn't display variables.

Comment: I saved it as `Application` (no Startup Screen, no Stay Open)

Comment: I've no clue what to do next. I wrote display dialog originalname after "end tell" but no dialog shows up.

Comment: The other thing is what OS are you using? I"m on Big Sur. Could be an OS update that's causing applescript old code to not work?

Comment: Did you remove (or comment out) the `try` block? I'm still on Mojave. Yes it could be that it's a Big Sur issue.

Comment: Yes I tried the remove try code but no success. I suspect it's a Big Sur applescript issue. I'm clueless now.

Comment: So anyone else want to help fix the above code? It's not working on Big Sur Macos. Thanks!

Comment: Ok i'll check and revert back. Thanks much!

Comment: Ok well, we're back to square one which is that the new code makes you choose the file via a "file open" dialog window. I was looking to drop a single image file on the app icon and get the copied text in clipboard.

Comment: I added the `on run` handler for testing reasons. The `on open` handler still exists.

Comment: Sorry on my computer I removed the "on run" / end run code and tried the code but it's not copying the info to the clipboard still. :(

Comment: It does work also with `on run` handler (to launch it with double-click) and this time I tested on Big Sur.

Comment: Ok but I don't want the open file dialog box. Can this be removed please?

Comment: Just don't use it. Once again the code works both as applet **and** as droplet.

Comment: Ok I confirm now that if the "on run" code is present and I select the file with that open dialog the code works. I already have this code working with an open file dialog box. I asked so that only the file drop to app gives same result.

Comment: On my machine with Big Sur it does.

Comment: Do you just cancel file open box?

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy your script works perfect. I used script editor and things look good. I'm marking your script as the correct answer. I'm very grateful for your patience.

Comment: Btw can a sound alert be added?